# After Jquery fadein/out animate an/some errors, buttons can't be clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a form that user can select a/some year form select-options list than add these to next select-list.
To achieve it, I've create 2 select-option and four buttons to add or remove.
The part to insert and remove are achieved but the problem appear when user click add button but there is/arenn't options selected.
The error-message is successful appeared with add jquery animate-fadein/out.
But when error-message have appeared, the button isn't accessible/cann't clicked.

Below is the HTML, and js.

**HTML**

```
<div id="segitiga" class="sgtg1" style="background-image: url('picture/left_triangle.png'); display: none"></div>
<div id="err_msg_border" class="err_msg_border1" style="display: none"></div>
<div id="err_msg" class="err_msg1" style="display: none;">Pilih satu atau lebih tahun untuk dimasukkan ke daftar sebelah kanan</div>                                                                        
<select id="list_tahun" style="width: 80px; margin-right: 5px" multiple="multiple" size="22"></select>

<input type="button" value="Add &gt; &gt" class="btn_tahun" id="A" >
<input type="button" value="Add All &gt; &gt" class="btn_tahun" id="AA">
<input type="button" value="&lt; &lt Remove" class="btn_tahun" id="R" disabled="disabled" >
<input type="button" value=" &lt; &lt Remove All" class="btn_tahun" id="RA" disabled="disabled">

<div id="segitiga" class="sgtg2" style="background-image: url('picture/right_triangle.png');display: none"></div>
<div id="err_msg_border" class="err_msg_border2" style="display:none"></div>
<div id="err_msg" class="err_msg2" style="display: none">Pilih satu atau lebih tahun yang akan dihapus</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
a = document.getElementById('list_tahun');
b = document.getElementById('list_tahun_pilihan');

$("#A").click(function() {
    count = 0;
    count2 = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < a.options.length; i++) {
        if (a.options[i].selected) {
            option = document.createElement("option");
            option.text = a.options[i].text;
            option.value = a.options[i].value;
            b.add(option);
            a.options[i].selected = false;
            a.options[i].disabled = true;
            count++;
        }
    }
    if (count < 1) {
        $(".sgtg1").fadeIn();            
        $(".err_msg_border1").fadeIn();
        $(".err_msg1").fadeIn();            
    } else if (count > 0) {
        $(".sgtg1").fadeOut();
        $(".err_msg_border1").fadeOut();
        $(".err_msg1").fadeOut();
        document.getElementById('R').disabled = false;
        document.getElementById('RA').disabled = false;
    }
    for (var i = 0; i < a.options.length; i++) {
        if (a.options[i].disabled) {
            count2++;
        }
    }

    if (count2 === a.options.length) {
        document.getElementById('A').disabled = true;
        document.getElementById('AA').disabled = true;
    } else {
        document.getElementById('A').disabled = false;
    }
});
```

....

How I can set up the focus again to the buttons ?
-Thanks-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After I inspect element with firefox, the height of area of error message -class="err_msg1" is too height and it's covered the buttons. So, when I want to click the button, the cursor will appear into class="err_msg1".

My advice, be crefully about specify each height-width of element so, when you want some of element runs well, don't let their layer are stacked.

Answer (score 0):

Your html is invalid.

First Change this:

```
<input type="button" value="Add>>" class="btn_tahun" id="A" >
```

To:

```
<input type="button" value="Add&gt;&gt" class="btn_tahun" id="A" >
```

Text like `<` or `>` should be written in code like this:

```
< ==> &lt;
> ==> &gt;
```

Comment: It done to fix this part but the problem still remains, some buttons still can't be clicked after fadein error message appear